# definition for "Webpack module"

Tags: webpack, webpack-hmr

When bundling a file with Webpack, a couple of things are injected.
Specifically, Webpack injects `module`, best known for the `.hot` property for HMR.
I can't find any documentation for this, and looking up "Webpack module" is not very productive.

Do you know of any definition/documentation/types for this `module`?